# Is astrology even true? If it is true, then how these Grahas called Devata become dumb bodies of Moon, Star Sun, Mars etc

Tags: scripture, gods, astrology, navagraha

Man is reaching Moon, satellites reached Saturn and Mangal. If these heavenly bodies are Devatas, Chandra and Surya being ''Vedic Deva''. Then how was Chandra Deva not able to stop or even react when Human beings, dogs and satellites landed on him. And if these are only physical entities, then why is it their effect is said to occur on us.

Is Surya Dev made of Hydrogen and Helium. If it is so, then is ParaBrahma Surya made of Atoms I.e. mass and energy?
Brahma is beyond mass, energy, existence or inexistence, then why is Surya Deva, not even able to move and is fixed in our solar system.

And if Surya Deva is not the one whom we see in sky, then why is it in our scriptures that Sun is eclipsed by rahu, the very rahu who was severed by Vishnu's Chakra?

If it is not the same Surya Deva, then this means either astrology is wrong, or it was a mistake of our Sages to write Ved Purans. And how did those sage, knower of Brahma, so careless as to make such great mistakes?

If it be argued that astrology does not at all work, then the other part of our Shastras giving knowledge of God is also false. And this means God is false and just a story. But we know God is true.

And if the planets in our solar system not the same Devatas as mentioned in our Scriptures, then why is that in our jyotish, the placement of these very celestial bodies is seen? And if the Upaayas done for curing them is also based on these very physical celestial bodies, then who is the consumer or see-er of these Upaayas, is he Brihaspati, Shani, Moon? And if it so, then what does Chandra Deva(a vedic God), do when man lands on his physical entity of Moon? Does Chandra Deva become happy or sad? Of is he not able to account for anything.

Mars Planet of our solar system is said to be ruled by Angaraka Mangal. Now, Mangal has to answer to his Prati-adhi-devata Subrahmanya Kartikkeya. So what does Mangal tell to Lord Kartikkeya, when a satellite comes on the Mars Planet or Mangal Graha. (I know planet is not the translation to Graha, but I'm just using it as a convention).

And if Human beings some day would start landing on Mars Planet, then what will Angaraka tell Kartikkeya? And will Kartikkeya , who is son of Shri Shiva, not even tell Lord Shiva about these things? And is then, even a stupid person be able to connect to Supreme Soul Shiva this easily?

If astrology is not a proper or complete Gyan or Vidya, and astrology is spread throughout our scriptures, then how can we say that our scriptures are correct? And if these are not correct, then what path we follow?

Comment: Joytisha is a vedanga.The main purpose of jyotiṣa is to prepare auspicious 
   date and time (muhurthas) for vedic yajnas ,based on position of planet's.Jyotisha only talks about  time keeping and calendar.Joythisha sometimes covers astronomy but at very basic level.Nothing is written about physical system of planets in joytishs.But only deals with their movement's.

Comment: Horoscopes or Hora joytish is separate branch of Joytisha ,which only deals with planets and their effect on our life based on kundali. Actually the word graha is referred to demons and not to actual planets.And this branch only deals with Graha upasana (planets)

Comment: I think Chandra and his associates must have amply threatened those people who landed on him in a language that they understand.

Comment: There could be a difference between the god Chandra and the satellite chandra. Note that in the western world, the names of roman gods have been reused for planets. Maybe 1000 years down the lane someone will ask why Jupiter / Neptune / Uranus / Saturn etc don't complain and how Jupiter is the son of Saturn etc.

Comment: These are deities associated with the planets and not the dumb bodies of the planets themselves.

Comment: @sv. This means - astrology is false. Now, astrology has been in various Scriptures, therefore verses in Scriptures are false.

Comment: @AnuragSingh IMO, scriptures were written like people like you and me so prone to errors. Considering every word of scripture to be true even if it defies logic, science and common sense, is a dangerous proposition.

Comment: BTW, I recently read this nice article: [An Indian Test of Indian Astrology](http://www.csicop.org/si/show/an_indian_test_of_indian_astrology)

Comment: @sv. the above article was really such an ignorant one. The writer had written it without any knowledge. Actually this is the problem. The science-based people have no knowledge of Scriptures, and think of themselves as greatest. The orthodox-based believers keep on disregarding science and come to no conclusion. Only a few take full knowledge of both sides and become in reality the greatest .

Comment: @Anurag What is that you didn't like in the article?
 Here's another video debate I saw on YouTube: https://youtu.be/JPnsRI-4d80

Comment: As per [this meta post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/72/1049), the topic astrology is ON topic, hence clicking to reopen.

Comment: "Is astrology even true? " there is no proof that it works hence we can assume it isn't true.

Answer (score 3):

As per arya samaj(which holds vedas as only true source), but still it is held that there is no devta existent and astrology etc are false.

So you may assume that vedas are true source and you may believe in one single God(represented by Om) and still holding astrology to be false is officially possible in Hinduism's one or many sects.

Just assume that all the puranic and other mythological stories as "mixture of analogies and some history and some literature stories" to inculcate dharma in followers. These puranic stories do not have to be taken 100% literally. Be vedic, esp upanishad follower.

Comment: also see Jyotish || Belief in Astrology - [Hindi]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lNGFsKYgyKg
by om swami. He is from different sect