# Where Lord Shiva used to reside during the time when the Himalaya did not exist?

Tags: shiva, kailasa

We know that the Himalaya range was formed out of the Tethys. We also know that Lord Shiva's abode is said to be the [Mount Kailash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Kailash).

So, where Lord Shiva used to reside before Himalaya was formed?

Comment: This is not scientific speculation and fine.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma okay. Then please explain how this question is marked scientific Speculation- [is astrology even....](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17875/is-astrology-even-true-if-it-is-true-then-how-these-grahas-called-devata-becom)

Comment: @AnuragSingh The question can be explained where Shiva used to reside before the  Himalayas formed but yes the first line makes the question problematic. If that is removed, the question is fine. Read answer https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15645/5212. You are using the broken window logic here. Your question was based on assumption that devatas are the grahas made of helium etc., and is based on the scientific speculation. Hence off-topic.

Comment: There were no human beings when Himalayas didn't exist. So how is it possible to answer this question?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma oh so helium is scientific , but collision of plates to emerge as mountain is not scientific. If the first line is removed, then question shall be fine.

Comment: If we say assuming Sun as helium is scientific, then assuming Himalaya emerging from Tethys is also scientific speculation and concept. How can we say Himalaya actually emerged from Tethys and tectonic plate collision?

Comment: I think that time Lord Shiva was supposed to live on shivaloka, which is not kailash mountain.